# Error: invalid path when trying to clone a Sapper project on Windows

Tags: windows, git, svelte, sapper

I am trying to clone a [Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.dev/) project on my **Windows machine** but I am getting the following error:

```
error: invalid path 'src/routes/[region(us|uk)]/profile/[id]/index.svelte'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
```

It seems like the error has something to do with the special characters (`[`, `]`, `(`, `)`, `|`) used in the directories' names. However, **this is how routing works** in [Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.dev/).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You have an extra `]` after `profile]`

Comment: @easwee - thanks, just removed it as this is just an example. That's not the real route but an example that contains all the special chars from the real one. I think the problem is the `|`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that the pipe character `|` is the problem.

The documentation makes no mention of pipe, and I would expect it to cause issues.

Furthermore, it is git which is causing an issue, so not really a Svelte/Sapper question.

I would recommend renaming your route as follows:

`src/routes/[region(u[sk])]/index.svelte`

Comment: On Unix/Linux only 2 (two) characters are reserved in the path names: NULL (`\000`) and slash (`/`). Everything else is allowed though of course not everything is recommended.